# Modify a function call captured in exp

Tags: r, functional-programming, metaprogramming

For example, changing `cumsum` in the output of `expr(cumsum(1:3))` to `cumprod`.

Currently the only thing I can think of is converting the output of `expr(cumsum(1:3))` to a string, editing it, then changing it back to a function call.

This seems like a pretty poor solution though and I'm struggling to find a better way.

```
library(rlang) 
f(expr(cumsum(1:4)), cumprod)
# [1] 1 2 6 24
```

This is basically what I'm trying to achieve. Can you help me find a starting point?

Comment: It's not clear to me how do you decide which function you want replace (because `:` is also a function). But if you want to always replace the outer one, you could define the following function `f <- function(x, y) {tmp <- substitute(x) ; tmp[1] <- substitute(y) ; eval(tmp)}` and then use it as follows `f(cumsum(1:4), cumprod())`

Comment: @DavidArenburg ; if you use `tmp[[1]] ` you can avoid the `()`

Comment: @user20650 good point.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks! This is exactly what I was hoping to find!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like @David Arenburg, so I'm posting his answer here and marking it.

It's not clear to me how do you decide which function you want replace (because : is also a function). But if you want to always replace the outer one, you could define the following

```
function f <- function(x, y) {
  tmp <- substitute(x) 
  tmp[[1]] <- substitute(y)  
  eval(tmp)
 }
```

and then use it as follows

```
f(cumsum(1:4), cumprod) 
#[1] 1 2 6 24
```

– David Arenburg

Answer (score 0):

If you just apply `gsub` to expression R casts it to character vector and does the substitution which you can cast as expression with `parse`:

```
y <- 1:4
x <- expression({cumsum(y)})

x.2 <- gsub("cumsum", "cumprod", x)
class(x.2)
# [1] "character"
x.2 <- parse(text = x.2)
eval(x)
# [1]  1  3  6 10
eval(x.2)
# [1]  1  2  6 24
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `rlang`

```
f <- function(ex, fn) {

   ex1 <- as.character(ex)
   fn <- enquo(fn)[-1]
   eval_tidy(parse_expr(glue::glue('{fn}({ex1[-1]})')))

   }
f(expr(cumsum(1:4)), cumprod)
#[1]  1  2  6 24
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you replaced cumsum with `cumprod` the output would be a vector 4 long, not 24, so we assume  you meant to replace it with `prod`.

We use `substitute` to substitute `cumsum` with the value of the `cumsum` argument and then evaluate the resulting expression.

`f` here uses no packages -- the input in the question uses `expr` from rlang but even that is not really needed since we could have used `quote(...)` in place of `expr(...)`.

```
f <- function(.x, cumsum) eval.parent(do.call("substitute", list(.x)))

# test
f(expr(cumsum(1:4)), prod)
## [1] 24

f(expr(cumsum(1:4)), cumprod)
## [1]  1  2  6 24
```